# Linker error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart_static while trying to compile CUDA code with clang

Tags: c++, cuda, clang, gpu, llvm

I tried to compile a axpy.cu file as specified in the official docs [here](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html):

```
clang++ axpy.cu -o exec --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_60 -L/usr/local/cuda -lcudart_static -ldl -lrt -pthread
```

But that gave a linker error and warning:

> clang: warning: Unknown CUDA version. cuda.h: CUDA_VERSION=11060. Assuming the latest supported version 10.1 [-Wunknown-cuda-version]

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart_static

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have clang version 11 installed.
On running:

```
nvidia-smi
```

I get:
[image]

I read somewhere that I need to add a symbolic link to libcudart file or something if that helps.

I get the following output on running:

```
ld -lcudart_static --verbose
```

```
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libcudart_static.a failed
ld: cannot find -lcudart_static
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /lib/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/cudart_static.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libcudart_static.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/cudart_static.a failed
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution. Apparently the linker wasnt able to locate libcudart binary. So used find to get its location:

```
find /usr/ -name libcudart_static*
```

Got its path as:

```
/usr/local/cuda-11.6/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart_static.a
```

(might be different for you).

Just linked this path by using -L flag in the compilation command.
New command:

```
clang++ axpy.cu -o exec --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_60 -L/usr/local/cuda -L/usr/local/cuda-11.6/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/ -lcudart_static -ldl -lrt -pthread
```